# How can I select multiple TextViews with different IDs in Java Android Studio like findViewById(R.id.)

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I am doing a project and this partly has a function of a search engine that highlights the words that are searched.

I have an EditText and a button that when pressing the button highlights the word in the EditText.
It works perfectly if you search for it in a single TextView as I assign the findViewById(R.id.textView1) to it
but how do I do if I have more than 100 TextView? I'm doing a long manual.
In addition, each TextField in the XML has different names.
For example textView1, txView1, textView2, txVi1, etc

Is it possible what I need to do? I looked in many places and couldn't find anything.

I leave you part of the .java code

```
public class Medicina extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText searchview;
Button btnBuscar;


boolean isHighlight = false;
TextHighlighter textHighlighter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_medicina);



    searchview = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchview);
    btnBuscar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);

    btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if (!isHighlight){
                textHighlighter = new TextHighlighter();

                textHighlighter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"))
                        .setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                        .addTarget()
                        .highlight(searchview.getText().toString(),TextHighlighter.BASE_MATCHER);
            }


            isHighlight = !isHighlight;
        }

    });


}
```

In the .addTarget() would go the findViewById (R.id.lalala)
And it would work if you only had a single TextView, but it's hundreds.

Thank you

The first almost 300 lines of XML code (from here on it's all the same, the vast majority TextView and ImageView).
I upload the code to GitHub because it gives me an error when pasting it in the post.

https://github.com/lautarovculic/activity_medicina

Comment: Attach the xml of `activity_medicina` with your question.

Comment: The first almost 300 lines (there are more than 3000 in activity_medicina, 90% are TextView)of XML code (from here on it's all the same, the vast majority TextView and ImageView).
I upload the code to GitHub because it gives me an error when pasting it in the post.

https://github.com/lautarovculic/activity_medicina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign an id for the `ViewGroup` that contains all the `TextView`. Then obtain the `ViewGroup` by `findViewById(R.id.viewgroup)` and loop through all `ViewGroup`'s child view to get all of its `TextView`.

```
public List<TextView> getAllTextViewsSimple() {
    final List<TextView> result = new ArrayList<>();
    final ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.viewgroup);
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View v = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
             result.add((TextView) v);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you want an even more general approach in case the `TextView` may not be placed in the same `ViewGroup`. Assign an id to the outmost `ViewGroup` then obtain and pass it as a parameter to a recursive function to get all child `TextView`.

```
public List<TextView> getAllTextViews(View v) {
    final List<TextView> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            result.addAll(getAllTextViews(viewGroup.getChildAt(i)));
        }
    } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
        result.add((TextView) v);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code snippet to help you use it with `TextHighlighter`

```
final List<TextView> allTextViews = getAllTextViewsSimple();
textHighlighter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"))
                        .setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

for (TextView tv : allTextViews) {
    textHighlighter.addTarget(tv);
}                    

textHighlighter.highlight(searchview.getText().toString(),TextHighlighter.BASE_MATCHER);
```

Comment: I am trying to know where to put the first code that you passed me and how the .java would look then
in the part of
public TextHighlighter addTarget () {
I get an error addTarget () says a missing ;

https://imgur.com/f1Bya5n

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Just place method `getAllTextViewsSimple` in your activity (outside of `onCreate` since I saw you placed the previous method in `onCreate` which was wrong). Call `getAllTextViewsSimple` whenever you need to get all the `TextView`

Comment: I've also added a snippet of code to help you use it with `TextHighlighter`

Comment: Ready !!! Many thanks!
It would be missing that when I look for another word the previous one that is highlighted is eliminated and do not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase but it is a minor detail that is not a priority now and it is not the case of the post.
Thank you very much again !!